# List all files in a homebrew package

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, homebrew

How can I get `homebrew` to list out all files installed for a package? For example, when I run `brew list` for the exim package, I get these files:

```
$ brew list exim
/usr/local/Cellar/exim/4.80.1/bin/exiwhat
/usr/local/Cellar/exim/4.80.1/bin/exiqsumm
/usr/local/Cellar/exim/4.80.1/bin/exiqgrep
/usr/local/Cellar/exim/4.80.1/bin/exipick
/usr/local/Cellar/exim/4.80.1/bin/exinext
/usr/local/Cellar/exim/4.80.1/bin/eximstats
/usr/local/Cellar/exim/4.80.1/bin/exim_tidydb
/usr/local/Cellar/exim/4.80.1/bin/exim_lock
/usr/local/Cellar/exim/4.80.1/bin/exim_fixdb
/usr/local/Cellar/exim/4.80.1/bin/exim_dumpdb
/usr/local/Cellar/exim/4.80.1/bin/exim_dbmbuild
/usr/local/Cellar/exim/4.80.1/bin/exim_ctl
/usr/local/Cellar/exim/4.80.1/bin/exim_checkaccess
/usr/local/Cellar/exim/4.80.1/bin/exim-4.80.1-3
/usr/local/Cellar/exim/4.80.1/bin/exim
/usr/local/Cellar/exim/4.80.1/bin/exigrep
/usr/local/Cellar/exim/4.80.1/bin/exicyclog
/usr/local/Cellar/exim/4.80.1/share/man/man8/exim.8
```

But there are files added to the system that is not in the list above. For example:

```
$ ls -ld /usr/local/etc/exim.conf 
-rw-r--r--  1 hanxue  admin  35904 Sep 25 21:11 /usr/local/etc/exim.conf
```

Answer (score 121):

Just add `-v` or `--verbose`, for example:

```
$ brew ls --verbose exim
```

Comment: While that recurses into installed directories and lists all the files they contain, it did not list the exim.conf file in the original post. It *was* added by the brew install action.

Comment: @MSpreij MacPorts actually does not have this problem since it tracks *all* files that will be installed before moving them into their final destination. Homebrew does not do this at all, so config files under `/usr/local/etc` and other places are there to stay unless one manually removes them. Homebrew only concerns itself with the program, not the settings or other remnants that the program leaves behind. [Here is a section from the MacPorts documentation explaining how they avoid this problem.](https://guide.macports.org/chunked/reference.phases.html#reference.phases.introduction)

Comment: Or `brew ls -v exim` for short.

Comment: So good works like a charm.

Answer (score 6):

If the package in question is a **cask** install (e.g. mactex) then you'll need to include the `--cask` arg to the list/ls command e.g.

```
brew ls --cask exim
```

Note: With casks if you don't include the `--cask` arg then it often reports an error. And with the `--cask` arg it may only list the installer dmg as it doesn't seem to track the resulting installed files.